# the expo prebuild process is never finished

Tags: react-native, build, expo

I ran into the need to access the native code in my existing expo project. However, after I entered the `npx expo prebuild` command, I saw

```
Creating native project directories (./ios and ./android) and updating .gitignore
```

in the terminal and that was it. This command never completes. At the same time, a normal build is performed without any problems

I tried creating a new project and calling the `npx expo prebuild` command again, this time I saw

```
Creating native directory (./android)
```

which also never completed.

Please tell me what the problem might be and how it can be solved?